# Did any stores of the medieval era have names?

Tags: medieval

I know it's common for shops and stores to be named in D&D and other fantasy settings, but how common was that practice in the medieval era (say, from 1000 AD onward)? It seems to me that inns and the like were named more often than, say, the workshops of smiths, traders, or other craftsmen and merchants.

I'm trying to be as "realistic" as possible with the campaign world I'm establishing, so if there's historical precedent, I'll feel better about it.

Edit: It's also been brought to my attention to clarify whether or not I mean this in a general or specific sense. The answer is the former. If the convention wasn't really present in Asian or Middle Eastern countries, for example, but was in European ones, that information still helps immensely. I'm just hoping to find out how popular the practice was in the medieval era.

Comment: This might be a better question for the History Stack Exchange

Comment: It also should probably be narrowed down some.  I wouldn't be surprised if conventions in England were different than conventions in Italy, for example.

Comment: @Ryan_L I get what you mean and I thought of that, but I mean it in a general sense. If it wasn't common in, say, Asian countries, but was in certain European ones, that information would still help a ton.

Comment: This is not answerable. First of all, middle age is a concept applicable to European history, not to Asia, Africa, America or Oceania. Then, there were thousands if not million of stores. We cannot know of all of them.

Comment: @L.Dutch: Various Asian nations, e.g., the Ottomans, the Persians, the Indians, the Chinese, or the Japanese had their own Middle Age periods. (Of course, they were not synchronized with the western European Middle Ages, which was not synchronized with eastern European Middle Ages anyway.)

Comment: You are asking a question without defining the meaning of your words; specifically, what do you mean by "having names"? There was no Chamber of Commerce, so quite obviously no business of any kind had a formal name, because there was nobody to register it. On the other hand, there were no postal numbers and no formal addresses, so by necessity every business was identified by some sort of name, either arbirary or descriptive. Tom's Smithy, the smithy with the sign of the Four Red Horseshoes, the Smithy by the Little Creek, the Smithy at the London Gate, etc.

Comment: As Halfthawed pointed out you'll get across to people who know a lot more if you post this question on the History Stack Exchange. One thing I would point out, however, is that very few people could read in this time so signage would be much more important - the red and white of a barber's or the snake and staff of medicine would indicate to the illiterate what sort of shop it was but to write "Bob the Barber" over your shop would mean nothing to your customers. Even now many British pubs still use pictures on their signs - I can speculate but History SE should be able to provide evidence.

Comment: I concur: this is not about worldbuilding per se.  It also shows a complete lack of prior research.  I see that you're new here, for which welcome!  I'm going to recommend that you take a look at our [tour] and [help] so that you can get a good idea what this forum is about.  SE enforces a pretty strict set of rules as to what kinds of queries we can handle here.  Your specific question is very easily answered by a web search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_companies   That said, I would strongly urge you come back here with more questions that are actually worldbuilding related!

Comment: AFAIK names came with companies / corporations, and that didn't happen until the late 1600s, and didn't really become a thing until the 1800s, as only the government could create a corporation until 1844, I think.  Before then there were trades.  Since everything was owned/run by individuals it was "John's shop" or "[FamilyName]'s shoppe".  I could be wrong, but AFAIK names came with corporation entities, not buildings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on hte history stack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that by "Medieval" you refer to Western Europe (As so many do, the rest of the world only appeared in the 16th century, I guess :) )

Retail establishments usually catered to locals only, and was chartered by a feudal lord (hence - no competition). All the local villagers and nobles referred to it by trade (blacksmith, carpenter, tailor) or by name (which is why so many family names ARE trade names "John Smith", "Arthur Fletcher", "Albert Shoemaker")

Only in cities did shops and workshops, under the scrutiny of guilds, allowed to compete. Only there did such establishment given a name (usually the master craftsman name - that apprentices kept for generation, long after the apprentice was the new master).

In the middle-east, where cities existed long before and there was no strict guild-system, shops and workshops were named after the patriarch whose family owned the place. In some places (Allepo, Beirut) shops had women names!

China is a different story altogether - shops had names to deter evil spirits, or draw good luck - and did not have direct connection (maybe intentionally?) to whatever was in there (I don't know about Japan, Korea and Thailand - I guess they followed China's example - but I would not count on it)

West Africa shops were usually of wandering traders, rarely having an establishment. North Africa follows the middle-east example. Horn of Africa has much older traditions - but I did not find references to shops (but it does not mean they did not have them). An Ethiopian colleague of mine explained that they referred to trade differently (I did not understand).

You should investigate about South America cultures... I do not know if they had shops. Neither Oceania.

Good luck!